# Fix request to PostgreSQL without Exception from UNIQUE rule

Tags: postgresql

I'm have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE recruiter (
        nickname TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        url_account TEXT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (nickname)
);

CREATE TABLE proposal (
        header TEXT NOT NULL,
        url_proposal TEXT NOT NULL,
        time_addition TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        nickname TEXT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (url_proposal, header),
        FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES recruiter (nickname)
);
```

And I insert in proposal table data with script:

```
INSERT INTO proposal (header, url_proposal, time_addition, nickname) VALUES ((?), (?), (?), (?))
```

Sometimes I have duplicate and rule `UNIQUE (url_proposal, header)` throws:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "proposal_url_proposal_header_key"
```

Please help me fix my script so that the exception is not thrown but the script worked the same way. Without duplicate without `Exception` insert in proposal table my data `(header, url_proposal, time_addition, nickname)` in one request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reject the new row:

```
INSERT INTO proposal (header, url_proposal, time_addition, nickname) 
VALUES ('header', 'url', now(), 'nick')
ON CONFLICT (url_proposal, header) DO NOTHING;
```

or if you want to update the existing row:

```
INSERT INTO proposal (header, url_proposal, time_addition, nickname) 
VALUES ('header', 'url', now(), 'nick')
ON CONFLICT (url_proposal, header)
DO UPDATE SET time_addition = excluded.time_addition, nickname = excluded.nickname;
```